# POSTing item from ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-controller

I have a simple ng-repeat, that displays a list of addresses. Next to each address is a button, when clicked, i want to perform a HTTP:POST. I know know how to perform a REST call, but im struggling to understand how to access the POST'ed item from the repeat in my controller:

HTML:

```
<form ng-submit="postAddress(address)">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="address in addresses">
            <p>{{address}}</p>                              
            <button>Add Address</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <p ng-show="addressSaved">Address Saved: {{addressSaved}}</p>
</form>
```

CTRL:

```
$scope.postAddress = function(address) {
    console.log(address);
    // My REST call goes here //////
    .success(
        $scope.addressSaved = true;
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In you case `address` variable which is in wrapper div, don't know what `address` is as `address` is defined in `ng-repeat`.

Basically you need to have separate `form` for each `field`, so that you can send out each address in post request using `ng-submit`.

**Markup**

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="address in addresses">
       <form ng-submit="postAddress(address)"
          <p>{{address}}</p>                              
          <button>Add Address</button>
       </form>
    </li>
</ul>
<p ng-show="addressSaved">Address Saved: {{addressSaved}}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-click for each button inside ng-repeat.

```
<form ng-submit="postAddress(selectedAdress)">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="address in addresses">
            <p>{{address}}</p>                              
            <button ng-click="selectedAdress = address">Add Address</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <p ng-show="addressSaved">Address Saved: {{addressSaved}}</p>
</form>
```

I hope it works. SelectedAdress will assign before form submit.
or you should give up submit.

```
<form >
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="address in addresses">
            <p>{{address}}</p>                              
            <button type="button" ng-click="postAddress(address )">Add Address</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <p ng-show="addressSaved">Address Saved: {{addressSaved}}</p>
</form>
```